# How can I insert html code inside a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables

So I am pulling information from google calendar and I need to divide the variables I am receiving so I can display them in different divs.  So what i need to do is something like this

```
var divMonth = '<div id ="rawr">';
var divMonthClose = '</div>';

dateString =  divMonth + monthName + divMonthClose + ' | ' + parseInt(dateMonth, 10);
```

However, as you imagine the result displayed is...

```
"<div id ="rawr">December</div> | 8"
```

It does not actually interpret the html and make the div layer. So my question is.. How can i insert html code within the variable so it actually works as html?  Is there a function I am missing or is it even possible?

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas you might have!

Comment: How are you adding that text to the page? In jquery you'd have to do something like `$('#somewhere').html(dateString)`.

Comment: li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' - ' + dateString));

Comment: There's your problem. `creatTextNode()` doesn't interpret html in the string. it's inserted as literal text.

Comment: Is there a way i can interpret html in the string then?

Comment: Since you've tagged this question with jquery, just use the `.html()` call. No need to use raw dom operations when you're on jquery.

Comment: Maybe i am missing a step or the syntax is wrong but I tried [code]  li.appendChild(document.html(' - ' + dateString));[/code] and nothing displayed.... Looking at the jquery page I don't really see a solid example to follow.  Any ideas?

Comment: that's not jquery syntax. it'd be `$('#someID').html(...)` if it was. You're using raw dom calls and would have to build up the new html, node-by-node.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marc, I guess I should of stated i'm unfamiliar with javascript and jquery... I tried what you suggested `$('#demo').html(<div id = "roor">dateString</div>);`  and nothing displayed... I assume i missed something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have this post tagged as jquery, so you could do something like so:

```
var monthName = 'December';
var dateMonth = 31;

var ele = $('<div></div>')
    .attr('id', 'rawr')
    .html(monthName + ' | '  + parseInt(dateMonth, 10));
$('#container').append(ele);
```

Comment: Almost exactly how I would do it. Although jQuery doesn't require properly closed tags in it's element constructor syntax.  So it can simply be `$('<div>')`

Comment: Using this methods results in 
[object Object] being displayed.

I inputted the code as follows.. editing the original 

[var dateString = $('<div></div>').attr('id', 'rawr')
    .html(monthName + ' | '  + parseInt(dateMonth, 10));
$('#container').append(dateString);]
  }
  return dateString;
}

Comment: @Zanrok the sample code I posted is expecting to append to the "container" element. if you are returning a datestring in a custom function then you will need to modify accordingly

Comment: @Jesse thanks.  I think i got it working.  I got the values displaying above... the function.  But with some CSS i think that will solve the issues hopefully.  Otherwise it displays at [object, Object]

Answer (score 5):

use the createElement function:

```
var elm = document.createElement('div');
elm.setAttribute('id', 'rawr');
elm.innerHTML = THE_CODE_AND_TEXT_YOU_NEED_INSIDE_THE_DIV;
```

when you want to add it to the document:

```
$('MYELEMENT').append(elm);
```

where MYELEMENT is (obviously) the element you want to append the new div to.

Comment: did you just wack `$('MYELEMENT').append(elm);` because the OP had tagged jquery, where document.getElementById("MYELEMENT").append(elm), would of done the same thing?

Comment: If you are using jQuery to append, you really dont need to use `createElement` since jQuery has a element constructor syntax that is a bit easier to use.

Comment: Even if the jQuery object-creaton syntax looks easier, this avoids the parsing stage. And yes, I added the jQuery part because jQuery has been tagged and the two syntaxes do the same thing, although the latter is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want the html structure to be something like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 ...
  <div id="date">
   <div id="rawr">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can create the html code and add the content with one line:

```
$("#wrapper").append('<div id="date"><div id="rawr">'+monthName+'</div> | '+parseInt(dateMonth, 10)+'</div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it without jQuery something like this would work:

```
var divMonth = document.createElement('div');
divMonth.id = 'rawr';

divMonth.innerHTML = monthName + ' | ' + parseInt(dateMonth, 10);

document.getElementById("where_you_want_to_put_this").appendChild(divMonth);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off separating your display from your logic and update a div or span (when you want display inline) using JQuery. Something like the following.

`<div id='rawr'>
 <span id='updateme'></span>
</div>`

`<script>
 $("#updateme").html(monthName);
</script>`